# Bubble chart basics in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bubble-chart

I am looking to understand the best way to plot bubble charts and it is surprisingly a bit more confusing than I expected.

Take a simple data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)

bubble_data <- data.frame(x = c(1, 1), y = c(1, 1), size = c(9, 16), type = c("A", "B"))

> bubble_data
  x y size type
1 1 1    9    A
2 1 1   16    B
```

If we make the size of the plotted bubbles equal to the `size` variable, then if done correctly, the areas of the plotted bubbles should be in the ratio of 9 to 16, or ~56%.

Plotting we get something that does not look anywhere close to a 56% ratio of the areas (and the bubbles are really small):

```
ggplot(bubble_data, aes(x = x, y = y, size = size, color = type)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.3)
```

[image: bubble1]

So we could create a new variable by scaling the underlying data by taking the square root of the original data (since area is proportional to the square of the radius), and then plot that:

```
 bubble_data_scaled <- bubble_data %>% 
  mutate(scaled_size = sqrt(size))

> bubble_data_scaled
  x y size type scaled_size
1 1 1    9    A           3
2 1 1   16    B           4

# plot with scaled size
ggplot(bubble_data_scaled, aes(x = x, y = y, size = scaled_size, color = type)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.3)
```

Which yields a plot that looks pretty much the same as the previous plot

[image: bubble2]

Finally, we would use the `scale_size_area` or `scaled size` on the original `bubble_data` data set

```
ggplot(bubble_data, aes(x = x, y = y, size = size, color = type)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.3) +
  scale_size_area()
```

But this does not seem to yield the correct result either, and one of the bubbles looks a bit offset.

[image: bubble3]

Which brings me to my question:  What is the correct way to plot a bubble chart where the areas of the bubbles would reflect the correct relative sizes of the underlying data, and how to scale the plot output so that the bubbles are easier to see?

Thanks!

Comment: Try with `scale_size(range = c(9, 16))` and other ranges, to adjust the size range of the points. From the function help: " specifies the minimum and maximum size of the plotting symbol "

Comment: `scale_size_area` works fine for me. I think your observation about one of the bubbles looking offset is due to your plotting device, which not have anti-aliasing. Look at the cairo or ragg packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get bubbles scaled by size, use `scale_size_area`. To get them bigger change the `max_size` parameter.

```
ggplot(bubble_data, aes(x = x, y = y, size = size, color = type)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.3) +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 20, breaks = (0:5)^2)
```

[image]

As for the offset appearance, that sounds like it's due to the rendering device not using anti-aliasing. This can make lines appear jagged, or shapes to look asymmetric at the pixel level. The default plot window device in windows, for instance, doesn't use anti-aliasing. You can add the `ragg` device and adjust the settings in RStudio to make that the default for the plot window. Or you can render using ggsave + `ragg` or `cairo` to get nice anti-aliasing.

To get coordinate-scale control over the bubble size (ie to make a bubble "x units wide" in coordinate space, you could use `ggforce::geom_circle`.